# Boot error hide.me

Tags: boot, 22.04, vpn

I upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and after upgrading and restarting the PC, I've got these two errors while it tries to boot.

```
[Failed] Failed to start Hide.me CLI connection to server.
[Failed] Failed to start Hide.me CLI connection to nl.
```

[image]

Hide.me is a VPN client that I previously installed. It seems it tries to connect to one of those VPN servers before booting system, but it can't.
How can I delete this client or make it skip this step?

Comment: It depends on how you installed it.

Comment: If the system doesn't boot the problem is not with the vpn.